# how to fill spaces between lines?

Tags: java, swing, line, paintcomponent

I am trying to make a simple paint program. I am trying to make a tool like pencil which allows free drawing. So far my codes are:

**NPaintMain**

```
public class NPaintMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NPaintWindow();
    }
}
```

**NPaintWindow**

```
public class NPaintWindow {
    private JFrame windowFrame;
    private String windowTitle;
    private NPaintCanvas canvas;
    private Container easel;    
    public NPaintWindow() {
        windowTitle = "NPaint - a simple paint program.";
        windowFrame = new JFrame(windowTitle);
        windowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(windowFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        windowFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        windowFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        canvas = new NPaintCanvas();
        easel = windowFrame.getContentPane();
        easel.add(canvas);   
        windowFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**NPaintCanvas**

```
public class NPaintCanvas extends JPanel {
    double x, y, px, py;
    ArrayList<Line2D> l;
    public NPaintCanvas() {
        new NPaintMouseEvents(this);
        x = y = px = py = 0;
        l = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for(Line2D ll: l){
                g2d.draw(ll);
            }
            l.add(new Line2D.Double(px, py, x, y));
            g.dispose();
            repaint();
    }
}
```

**NPaintMouseEvents**

```
public class NPaintMouseEvents implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener {

    NPaintCanvas canvas;

    public NPaintMouseEvents(NPaintCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.canvas.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(canvas.px == 0 && canvas.py == 0){
           canvas.px = e.getX();
            canvas.py = e.getY();
        }
        canvas.x = e.getPoint().x;
        canvas.y = e.getPoint().y;
        canvas.px = canvas.x;
        canvas.py = canvas.y;
    }
}
```

My main problem here is that while dragging the points are drawn but they have space between them [like this](https://s31.postimg.org/muo3q5z4b/Capture.png). I want joined continuous line. Any help with further tips will be appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this. 1) Draw a `Line2D` between current and last point. 2) Add all the points to a `GeneralPath` and draw that each time a new point is added. BTW: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). To do that for this case, it would be necessary to reduce all classes aside from the `main(String[])` class to default and past them in at the end of `NPaintMain`, then add the imports.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i'm not sure I got that right.

Comment: See the edited comment.. Oh, right, I had not (never do) look closely at code until there is an MCVE, compiled in my IDE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you draw a single point to each mouse dragging move.

For each drawn line : the x1 and x2 are the same  and the y1 and the y2 are the same.
 
You should trace a line between two different points.
I have updated your code to handle that by introducing two different points : prev and actual points. 
To explain simply, a line is drawn only when the previous and the actual points have values. 
 And when a line is drawn, the last actual drawn point becomes the previous point for the next drawn line. In this way, you don't have holes between lines.

In canvas Class :

```
if (previousPoint != null && actualPoint != null) {
     l.add(new Line2D.Double(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, actualPoint.x, actualPoint.y));
     previousPoint = new Point(actualPoint.x, actualPoint.y);
}
```

If you release your mouse button, the previous and the actual points are set to null.

In Event class :

```
 @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      canvas.mouseReleased();
    }
```

In canvas Class :

```
  public void mouseReleased() {
    previousPoint = null;
    actualPoint = null;
  }
```

In this way, you can draw multiples lines in a independent way if you want.

Also, i have simplified the code by using Point instances (instead of doubles)which use ints for coordinates but you can use multiple doubles fields, it changes not a lot of things in practice.

```
package paint;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NPaintCanvas extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Line2D> l;
    Point actualPoint;
    Point previousPoint;

    public NPaintCanvas() {
    new NPaintMouseEvents(this);
      l = new ArrayList<>();
    }



  @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Line2D ll : l) {
            g2d.draw(ll);
        }
        if (previousPoint != null && actualPoint != null) {
            l.add(new Line2D.Double(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, actualPoint.x, actualPoint.y));
            previousPoint = new Point(actualPoint.x, actualPoint.y);
        }
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased() {
        previousPoint = null;
        actualPoint = null;
    }

    public void mousePressed(int x, int y) {
        previousPoint = new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

NPaintMouseEvent

```
package paint;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class NPaintMouseEvents implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    NPaintCanvas canvas;

    public NPaintMouseEvents(NPaintCanvas canvas) {
      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
      this.canvas.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      if (canvas.actualPoint == null) {
         canvas.actualPoint = new Point();
      }
      canvas.actualPoint.x = e.getPoint().x;
      canvas.actualPoint.y = e.getPoint().y;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      canvas.mousePressed((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      canvas.mouseReleased();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :). I know it is not asked in this question but can you help me on this -> last point and new point are joined even after releasing mouse and starting at some other corner of panel. Is it because that I am using ArrayList? can you help me on this just a little ?

Comment: You are welcome :)
no, it should not. It has not relation with you list.
My example code calls  canvas.mouseReleased(); in the event class to avoid it. You have maybe forget to copy something from my example. I explain it in my answer.

Comment: Calling `repaint` in `paintComponent` is wrong/useless. See my answer

Comment: @krzydyn You are completely right but you learn me nothing.
The code you quote is not from me, it comes from the original version I didn't modify. 
You saw that in the original code, multiple things may be improved. 
I answered to the question with some changes to ease the code modification for drawing lines, I would not rewrite all the code to make it a perfect code. It is not the question and SO is not done for doing full code reviews.

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad habbit :)

Answer (score 2):

Your are modifying your object state in `paintXXX` - that is wrong.
`paint` methods are for only paint the current state.

You should add mouse points to the list in a `MouseListener` and call `rapaint` to mark your `canvas` class to be repainted in `EDT`.

And `paintComponent` should always only draw the current list.

So you should do it this way:

```
public class NPaintCanvas extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Line2D> l;
    public NPaintCanvas() {
        new NPaintMouseEvents(this);
        l = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for(Line2D ll: l){
                g2d.draw(ll);
            }
    }
}


public class NPaintMouseEvents implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener {

    NPaintCanvas canvas;
    Point2D prev;
    public NPaintMouseEvents(NPaintCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.canvas.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (prev==null) {
            prev=e.getPoint();
            return;
        }
        Point2D p = new Line2D.Double(e.getPoint().x,e.getPoint().y);
        if (p.equals(prev)) return ; //not really moved
        canvas.l.add(prev, p);
        p=prev;
        canvas.repaint();
    }
}
```

Note: for optimal solution you should keep points and use `GeneralPath`.